# How to handle Authentication tokens

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a API mobile service that handles users' login and verification. If a user is verified then it produces an authentication token. On my end I have a Web client that receives that token and uses it to call different Api controllers. How should I go about keeping a user logged in status constant?

Can I store the token on a cookie? would it be exposed to abuse if I do so? would a session work better? What is the best way to handle this issue? Sorry for the noob question, but I have never done this type of setup before.

Comment: Is the client is Web browser?  how you are attaching the token to your request?

Comment: I have two clients really a mobile app and a Web MVC application. The MVC hits the API with a login request and the API sends back a token that can be added to the header of every request as a form of verification.

Comment: Ok,if you are going to use ssl, then it is safe to store in cookie. Do everyone using mobile app ll have different credentials for api access or they'll share common token?

Comment: The token is created based on each individual user login credentials. Right now the token is setup with a timespan of 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token can be stored relatively securely on the client as a cookie. Here's [an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt(v=vs.110).aspx) using Forms Authentication. It can be made even more secure by requiring SSL.

You can also consider using HTML 5 local storage like this:
http://www.princesspolymath.com/princess_polymath/?p=396

...which can be more efficient, as you manually use the token when making AJAX calls that require it instead of sending the cookie on every single request.

Comment: I guess the general agreement is that a cookie is safe enough. Local storage looks really cool, nice touch.